# async BlobClient.stage_block() regularly raises exception for 'HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I'm using the python SDK to upload a block to an Azure Bob Storage Container. I need to do a partitioned upload so I'm using the `BlobClient.stage_block(...)` call. For performance reasons, I'm using the asynchronous version of the BlobClient (`azure.storage.blob.aio`).

Staging the first block is no problem, the second block usually also runs ok but with the third or fourth block, I'm getting an exception telling me that the server doesn't support the HTTP-Verb:

```
.\src\venv\Scripts\python.exe .\tests\minimal_example.py
Starting.
bytes_transfered=0, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=10485760, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=20971520, file_size=601070298
Unexpected return type <class 'str'> from ContentDecodePolicy.deserialize_from_http_generics.
Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

ErrorCode:None
Content: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

bytes_transfered=20971520, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=31457280, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=41943040, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=52428800, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=62914560, file_size=601070298
bytes_transfered=73400320, file_size=601070298
Unexpected return type <class 'str'> from ContentDecodePolicy.deserialize_from_http_generics.
Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

ErrorCode:None
Content: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

bytes_transfered=73400320, file_size=601070298
```

My target code is a little more complicated on the generator side but a minimalistic example to reproduce the behavior looks like this:

```py
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient, BlobClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
import asyncio


CREDENTIALS = DefaultAzureCredential()
CHUNK_SIZE = 4096
BLOCK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024
FILE = Path("large_file")
BLOB_NAME = f"test_blob{datetime.datetime.now().ctime()}"


async def generator(current_pos: int):
    with open(FILE, "br") as fd:
        fd.seek(current_pos)
        data = fd.read(4096)
        while data:
            yield data
            data = fd.read(4096)


async def upload():
    print(f"Starting.")
    async with ContainerClient(ACCOUNT_URL, CONTAINER, CREDENTIALS) as cc:
        async with cc.get_blob_client(BLOB_NAME) as blob:
            bytes_transfered = 0
            file_size = FILE.stat().st_size
            blocks = []
            excp_counter = 0
            while bytes_transfered < file_size:
                gen = generator(bytes_transfered)
                print(f"bytes_transfered={bytes_transfered}, file_size={file_size}")
                id = str(uuid4())
                length = min(BLOCK_SIZE, file_size - bytes_transfered)
                try:
                    await blob.stage_block(block_id=id, data=gen, length=length)
                    blocks.append(id)
                    bytes_transfered += length
                    excp_counter = 0
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")
                    excp_counter +=1  
                
                    if excp_counter > 2:
                        raise RuntimeError("Cannot upload!")

            blob.commit_block_list(blocks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = upload()
    asyncio.run(f)
```

When I handle the exception by basically ignoring it and retrying, the second or third attempt to stage the block works but with subsequent blocks, the issue happens again and again for an error rate somewhere between 30 and 70%.

Is this a bug in the BlobClient Code or am I using it wrong?

Used versions:

```
.\src\venv\Scripts\pip.exe freeze
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
autopep8==2.0.2
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.28.0
azure-functions==1.15.0
azure-functions-durable==1.2.5
azure-identity==1.14.0
azure-keyvault==4.2.0
azure-keyvault-certificates==4.7.0
azure-keyvault-keys==4.8.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-storage-blob==12.17.0
```

### EDIT 2023-10-06

I changed the generator function to better represent the use case. It's still much simplified since actually I'm using aiohttp to simultaneously download a file from another source. The output was changed accordingly to the test with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in the BlobClient Code or am I using it wrong?

The problem is that the **`generator`** function is consumed before the block is entirely uploaded. This is due to the **`generator`** function being used multiple times, and each time it is run, it begins reading from the beginning of the file.

So you can alter the generator function to keep track of the current location in the file and begin reading from that place each time it is called.

You have to modify the code in the **`upload`** function to use the generator function only once and use the **`__anext__()`** method to get the next chunk of data from the generator.

Here is the updated code which successfully uploaded the file using the async process.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import asyncio
import uuid

ACCOUNT_URL = "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net"
CONTAINER = "test"
CREDENTIALS = DefaultAzureCredential()
BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024
FILE = Path("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\sample326.pdf")
BLOB_NAME = f"test_blob_{datetime.datetime.now().ctime()}.pdf" 

async def generator():
    with open(FILE, "rb") as fd:
        data = fd.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        while data:
            yield data
            data = fd.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

async def upload():
    gen = generator()
    print(f"Starting. Type: {type(gen)}")
    async with ContainerClient(ACCOUNT_URL, CONTAINER, CREDENTIALS) as cc:
        async with cc.get_blob_client(BLOB_NAME) as blob:
            bytes_transferred = 0
            file_size = FILE.stat().st_size
            blocks = []
            excp_counter = 0
            while bytes_transferred < file_size:
                print(f"bytes_transferred={bytes_transferred}, file_size={file_size}")
                block_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
                length = min(BLOCK_SIZE, file_size - bytes_transferred)
                try:
                    data_chunk = await gen.__anext__()
                    await blob.stage_block(block_id, data_chunk, length)
                    blocks.append(block_id)
                    bytes_transferred += length
                    excp_counter = 0
                except StopAsyncIteration:
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
                    excp_counter += 1
                    if excp_counter > 2:
                        raise RuntimeError("Cannot upload!")

            await blob.commit_block_list(blocks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(upload())
```

**Output:**

```
Starting. Type: <class 'async_generator'>
bytes_transferred=0, file_size=21099096
bytes_transferred=4194304, file_size=21099096
bytes_transferred=8388608, file_size=21099096
bytes_transferred=12582912, file_size=21099096
bytes_transferred=16777216, file_size=21099096
bytes_transferred=20971520, file_size=21099096
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Update:**

you can also use async for loop.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import asyncio
import uuid

ACCOUNT_URL = "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net"
CONTAINER = "test"
CREDENTIALS = DefaultAzureCredential()
BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024
FILE = Path("C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\sample326.pdf")
BLOB_NAME = f"test_blob_{datetime.datetime.now().ctime()}.pdf" 

async def generator():
    with open(FILE, "rb") as fd:
        data = fd.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        while data:
            yield data
            data = fd.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

async def upload():
    async with ContainerClient(ACCOUNT_URL, CONTAINER, CREDENTIALS) as cc:
        async with cc.get_blob_client(BLOB_NAME) as blob:
                bytes_transferred = 0
                file_size = FILE.stat().st_size
                blocks = []
                excp_counter = 0
                async for i in generator():
                    print(f"bytes_transferred={bytes_transferred}, file_size={file_size}")
                    block_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
                    length = min(BLOCK_SIZE, file_size - bytes_transferred)
                    try:
                        await blob.stage_block(block_id, i, length)
                        blocks.append(block_id)
                        bytes_transferred += length
                        excp_counter = 0
                    except StopAsyncIteration:
                      break
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
                        excp_counter += 1
                        if excp_counter > 2:
                            raise RuntimeError("Cannot upload!")
        await blob.commit_block_list(blocks)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(upload())
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I didn't think the generator logic was significant so I kept it as simple as possible. I edited the example to better represent the use case. I also updated the storage-blob package to 12.18.2. The issue persists.

Comment: Hi, @MatthiasHolzapfel Is there any limitation in using `gen.__anext__()`? or Are you facing any errors with my approach?

Comment: I tried with async for loop check the updated answer.

Comment: Both, `gen.__anext__()` and the `async for` will give me a new blob_block for each 4096 bytes (in this example).
But that is not what I need. I need the generator to be passed to the `stage_block()` call so that I get an interleaved download/upload of my file (using aio).
I use multiple `stage_block()` calls to have a possibility to perform retries for a large (~100G) file transfer. So I need two levels of chunking.